# How to setup ImageTools in TinyMce

Tags: tinymce

I have added a ImagePlugin as described in https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/imagetools/#sdkinstallation.

I can modify a photo in an editor but I don't know how to save it after modifications.

After posting a form with wysiwyg I get :

> Cannot convert
>   blob:http://10.48.200.155/5e32b981-6e33-48cc-87b1-512abd653912 to
>   Blob. Resource might not exist or is inaccessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the image editing tools to modify an image the editor creates a Base64 encoded new image.  This exists (right after the editing) only in the browser.  To permanently save the image to something other than Base64 you need to follow these instructions:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

The net is that the editor can be configured to send the image binary to a script of your choice.  That script needs to save the image somewhere appropriate and return JSON with the path to the new image's location.